# auto-move email back to Inbox on flagged due date

Tags: vba, ms-office, office-2010

I am wondering how I can make it so when flagged e-mails are due they move from some folder to the Inbox.

Essentially, I have written some VBA that makes Outlook work like Inbox by Google. The VBA:

- lets me "snooze" e-mails in the Inbox for a number of days I pick and hide it (using view filters)
- if a new e-mail comes in matching a "snoozed" e-mail then it categories the message with a message so when I open the e-mail I'll know there are e-mails in the same conversation that are hidden

  - when the a "snoozed" email's timer is up it automatically shows back up in the Inbox

Right now my code "hides" the e-mail by using View filters:

```
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10900003" = 1 OR
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10900003" = 0 OR
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062003-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/81050040" <= 'Today' OR
"urn:schemas:httpmail:messageflag" IS NULL
```

However, I was thinking, instead of hiding it I should move "snoozed" e-mails to another folder.

The part I'm stuck with is moving the e-mails back to the Inbox after their timer is up.

I guess I need some way to hook into something that triggers when a flagged e-mails due date has approached?

The reason I want to do this is because if someone sends me an email that **they** have flagged then because my view filter hides all flagged messages the e-mail will come in as hidden and I won't see it until its due.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to trap the Application.Reminder event, which supplies the Item object which triggered the event.  However this requires that flags also have a reminder set on them.  The only other alternatives is to scan the Mailbox on a timer or Outlook start - or the ToDo List - and calculate the due dates for every flagged item.

Comment: Dang. Understood. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this client-side using a view filter. This is outlined really well on [this website](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-convert-your-inbox-to-do-list-snoozing-emails-microsoft-govani), but I'll post a summary here for completeness.

1. Create a new snooze view
   Click on View tab.

Click Change View.
Select Save Current View As a New View... from the menu.

Give a name to the new view like Snooze Email or To-do list View.
Select All Mail and Post Folders option from the radio button.
Click OK.

This new view is not compulsory to create but this creation will give you the option to go back to your original view smoothly whenever you like to do so.

2. Apply filters
   Click on View Settings under the View tab.

Click on Filter... button.

Click on Advanced tab.
To define a criterion, select the Field > Frequently-used fields > Due Date.

Select does not exist Condition from the drop-down list.
Press Add to List.

To add another criterion, select the Field > Frequently-used fields > Due Date.
Select On or before Condition from the drop-down list.
In Value field, type Today.
Press Add to List.
To add the third criterion, select the Field > Frequently-used fields > Flag Status.
Select not equal to Condition from the drop-down list.
In Value field, select Completed.
Press Add to List.
Click OK.
As soon as you press OK, all the email with due dates provided or completed flag will disappear from your inbox. Mail with due dates will reappear on your inbox on the due date.

3. Apply Flags

Right-click on the flag (symbol) against the top-most email in your inbox.
Select an appropriate option (when do you want to reappear the email in the inbox?)
Just to remind you that setting an item to This Week will set the reappear/due date to the upcoming Friday and Next Week will set it to the following Monday. You can choose Custom... to set any specific date you want to have it reappear as well, even telling Outlook to throw a reminder if you like.
This is an important step. The first time it may seem tedious, but there is an alternative to do that by using the move to folder tool for the emails which do not require your actions.

How to snooze the whole email conversation?
Because most of the readers are asking this question, I thought I should include it in the article.

If you are using the conversation view in the outlook, follow few more steps.

1. Open the conversation by clicking on the triangle on the left.
2. Select the subject line of the email conversation.
3. Apply flag to the subject line (whole email conversation).

Start Snoozing Email
Once you have applied filter, all you need to do is when you receive any new email, you just need to provide a flag to it. It will reappear at your convenient date, until that day it will be out of sight, out of mind. So you do not need to worry about the emails which are not important to you. Rather deleting it, you can mark them with Completed Flag Status and it will be disappeared forever. (Tip: You can use Quick Step Done to do it with one click.)

If you ever wish to see all the emails again, go back to View tab and change to your original view.